# How to fix "unmet dependencies" error with apt

Tags: apt

I  entered the following command on ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

It gives the following error

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.59-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 10.2.13+maria~trusty is to be installed
W: Duplicate sources.list entry https://repo.skype.com/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.skype.com_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you try the suggested `apt-get update`?

Comment: Did you search the /etc/apt tree for `repo.skype.com`?  Also run `apt-mark showhold` to see the held packages.

Answer (score 3):

You have MariaDB installed instead of MySQL, and are trying to install MySQL's version of the development package. That results in a dependency conflict. The equivalent MariaDB package is named slightly differently: it's `libmariadb-dev`.

`libmariadb-dev` also has a `Provides: libmysqlclient-dev` in its package metadata, so it will satisfy any dependencies for `libmysqlclient-dev`.

So try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmariadb-dev
```

---

To clear the warning about the Skype repository, check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and all files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory, and ensure that the Skype repository is mentioned only once.

The newer Skype packages will drop a repository configuration file into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory, while older ones didn't so you've probably added the Skype repository manually. Now you can remove your manual addition.